# Checking dynamic amount of deferreds of for example file uploads

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, jquery-deferred

## Context

The situation as follows: Users can upload files in an application. They can do this at any time (and number of times).

I would like to show a spinner when any uploading is being done, and remove it when no uploading is happening at the moment.

## My approach

The uploads are handles by an external file upload plugin (like blueimp) and on it's add method I grab the jqXHR object and add these to a backbone collection (which are images in my application, so I use this in combination with Marionette's collectionviews).

The following is part of a function called in an onRender callback of a Marionette Itemview:

```
// Get the file collection
var uploadFiles = SomeBackBoneCollection;

// Track how many deferreds are expected to finish
var expected = 0;

// When an image is added, get the jqXHR object
uploadFiles.bind('add', function(model) {
    // Get jqXHR object and call function which tracks it
    trackUploads(model.get('jqXHR'));

    // Do something to show the spinner
    console.log('start the spinner!');

    // Track amount of active deferreds
    expected++;
}, this);

// Track the uploads
function trackUploads(jqXHR) {
    $.when(jqXHR).done(function(){
        // A deferred has resolved, subtract it
        expected--;

        // If we have no more active requests, remove the spinner
        if (expected === 0) {
            console.log('disable the spinner!');
        }
    });
}
```

## Discussion

This method works very well, although I'm wondering if there are any other (better) approaches.

What do you think about this method? Regarding this method, do you see any up- or downsides? Any other methods or suggestions anyone?

For example, it might be great to have some kind of array/object to which you can keep passing deferreds, and that a $.when is somehow monitoring this collection and resolves if at any moment everything is done. However, this should work such that you can keep passing deferred objects at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via events.

I am assuming each file is an instance of this model:

```
App.Models.File = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

before the user upload the file, you are actually creating a new model, and save it.

```
uploadedFiles.create(new App.Models.File({...}));
```

so in your upload view...

```
//listen to collection events
initialize: function() {
  //'request' is triggered when an ajax request is sent
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'request', this.renderSpinner);
  //when the model is saved, sync will be triggered
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.handleCollectionSync);
}

renderSpinner: function() {
  //show the spinner if it is not already being shown.
}
```

ok, so, in 'handleCollectionSync' function, you want to decide if we wanna hide the spinner.
so how do we know if there're still models being uploaded? you check if there're new models in the collection (not saved models)

so in your collection, add a helper method:

```
 App.Collections.Files = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   //if there's a new model, return true
   hasUnsavedModels: function() {
     return this.filter(function(model) {
       return model.isNew();
     }).length > 0;
   }
 });
```

back to your view:

```
 handleCollectionSync: function() {
   //if there's no unsaved models
   if(!this.collection.hasUnsavedModels()){
     //removespinner
   }
 }
```

this should solve your problem assuming all the uploads are successful. you may want to complete this with error handling cases - it depends on what you wanna do with error case, but as long as you are not retrying it right away, you should remove it from the collection.

==========================================================================================

**Edit**

I'm thinking, if you allow the user to upload a file multiple times, you are not really creating new models, but updating existing ones, so the previous answer would not work. to work around this, I would track the status on the model itself.

```
App.Models.File = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.uploading = false; //default state
    this.on('request', this.setUploading);
    this.on('sync error', this.clearUploading);
  }
});
```

then setUploading method should set uploading to true, clearUploading should change it to false;

and in your collection:

```
hasUnsavedModels: function() {
  return this.filter(function(model) {
    return model.uploading;
  }).length > 0;
}
```

so in your view, when you create a new file

```
uploadNewFile: function(fileAttributes) {
  var newFile = new App.Model.File(fileAttributes);
  this.collection.add(newFile);
  newFile.save();
}
```

I believe 'sync' and 'request' events are triggered on the collection too when you save models inside of it. so you can still listenTo request, sync, and error events on the collection, in the view.

Comment: While this is nice approach although it makes me think! It's not entirely the same as my case in a sense that the uploads are being handled by (any) fileuploader plugin. I never save the models themselves, since I don't have to. I just track the images upload progress through this method. However, maybe using models which save (and thus upload) is also a good way to go. In that case I think I only need a fileinput button instead of a whole plugin; the uploading is done in the saving of the model.

Comment: Clarified the difference a bit in the question.

Comment: edited my answer with more details (and another approach) . since you are using collections already, why not use models? btw, in your original approach, attaching jqXHR to the model is not a problem until you get too many models ... since now all the jqXHR has a reference to it (its model), they will never be garbage collected until you remove your models from the memory.

Comment: and one other issue would be ... you have a state (var expected = 0;) being manipulated by two functions in two different scopes. this may cause problems in the long run, and make your app harder to maintain. (someone trying to fix something in one function will have to make sure 'expected' still works in others, and he gotta find all of the places that use the same variable as well!)

Comment: Regarding the garbage collection, that's a good point! What if i delete the jqXHR object once it has resolved? You've a good point regarding the state variable, any suggestions for that particular case if I were to use this method?

Comment: it really depends on the structure of your app. there're lots of ways to do it, it's hard to say which one is the 'best'.

Comment: I agree with you on that! Thanks for pointing out the possible pitfalls though :)